# Taylor series as an approximation for cos(θ)

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, triangles

So I was watching one of Walter Lewin's lectures and he writes down that...

$L(1-\cos \theta)=L\frac{\theta ^2}{2}$

This was evaluated by using the first 2 terms in the taylor series for cosθ which makes sense however he then writes down

$L(1-\cos \theta)=\frac{x^2}{2L}$  (???How did he come to this conclusion???)

Here is a sketch I drew to help visualize the situation. It involves the motion of a pendulum, but since the specific problem has to do with the taylor approximation here seems like a suiting place for the problem. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Well, do you know what the Taylor series for cosine is?

Comment: Yea, I know what the taylor series for cosine is, but my problem is I don't know how he ended up writing L(1-cos(θ))=x^2/2L What's the link between the angle theta and x, that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Can you compute something with a *different* trig function?

Comment: The specific problem mention was L(1-cosθ) I just don't see how x was brought into the equation to form L(1-cosθ) = x^2/2L  He explains that this was calculated using a taylor approximation but the Taylor series for cos(θ)= 1- θ^2/2 .... Where does the x come from??

Comment: Compute $\sin \theta$ in terms of $x$ and $L$, remembering your trigonometry. Then write down the Taylor series for sine.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sin\theta=x/L$. And when $\theta$ is small, we have $\sin\theta\approx\theta$. Hence $\theta\approx x/L$.

Substituting this into your first equation gives the second.

Answer (score 0):

These are approximations, appropriate for small $\theta$, not equalities.

The Taylor series gives
$$1-\cos\theta=\frac{\theta^2}2-\frac{\theta^4}{24}+\cdots.$$
For small $\theta$, $\theta^4/24$ etc., are much smaller than $\theta^2/2$
and so we have the approximation
$$1-\cos\theta\approx\frac{\theta^2}2$$
so that
$$L(1-\cos\theta)\approx L\frac{\theta^2}2.$$

In your triangle $x=L\sin\theta\approx L\theta$
using the series
$$\sin\theta=\theta-\frac{\theta^3}6+\cdots.$$
Substituting $x/L$ for $\theta$ gives
$$L(1-\cos\theta)\approx\frac{x^2}{2L}.$$

All of this is standard theory of the simple pendulum.